# How get all users id which liked the photo on VK

Tags: api, vk

Photo page:
http://vk.com/id98429809?z=photo98429809_299166823%2Falbum98429809_0%2Frev

Owner id: 3734832

**I'm using this code:**

```
$res = file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/likes.getList?type=photo&owner_id='3734832'&page_id='98429809'&page_url=http://vk.com/id98429809?z=photo98429809_299166823%2Falbum98429809_0%2Frev');

$resp = json_decode($res, true);

echo 'Count Likes: '.$resp['response']['count'];
```

**but I've got an error:**

```
{"error":{"error_code":100,"error_msg":"One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: item_id is undefined","request_params":[{"key":"oauth","value":"1"},{"key":"method","value":"likes.getList"},{"key":"type","value":"photo"},{"key":"owner_id","value":"3734832"},{"key":"page_id","value":"98429809"},{"key":"page_url","value":"http:\/\/vk.com\/id98429809?z=photo98429809_299166823\/album98429809_0\/rev"}]}}
```

How to get all users id which liked the photo?

Tell me please where is the error?

Answer (score 4):

1) To get likes for all items except widgets, you should use `item_id` parameter instead of `page_url`
2) You entered wrong owner_id

The right API request is:

https://api.vk.com/method/likes.getList?type=photo&owner_id=98429809&item_id=299166823